# InvalidAccessKeyId when reading from AWS S3 in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read from and write to AWS S3 using PySpark running on Ubuntu 20.04, Spark 3.1.2, Hadoop 3.2, Java 11.

I am launching PySpark with these extra Java packages:

```
pyspark --packages=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.563,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2
```

Then, s3a is configured as follows:

```
hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.access.key', 'my_access_key')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.secret.key', 'my_secret_key')
```

However, when I try to read with  `df = spark.read.csv('s3a://sample_bucket_name/sample.csv')`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 737, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.csv.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://********/sample.csv: getFileStatus on s3a://*********/sample.csv: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: *********; S3 Extended Request ID: ****************), S3 Extended Request ID: ****************:403 Forbidden
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.isDirectory(S3AFileSystem.java:3044)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: ****************; S3 Extended Request ID: ****************), S3 Extended Request ID: ****************
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4920)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4866)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$getObjectMetadata$4(S3AFileSystem.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2264)
    ... 22 more
```

I have confirmed that the IAM credentials I am using are valid and have permission to access the target bucket on S3.  Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the advice in https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/538#issuecomment-356169100 setting: `hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true");` ?

Comment: @YannStoneman - Yes, no luck with that either.  Raises a different error.